# ChangeDetection not triggering in .subcribe() in RC.5?

Tags: angular

I have an app currently running in RC.4 that I'm upgrading to RC.5. I've stopped using the old Forms directives and I've updated to use NgModule to get the app started.

However I immediately run into a problem due to my app loading much of it's information through ajax calls. I subscribe to these Observables and put the data on the component like I always have in RC.4. The usual line looks something like this:

```
api.GoGetData().subscribe((data) => this.myData = data);
```

In RC.4 this worked without any issues. Now that I'm getting RC.5 up and running I'm finding that the View isn't updating to show this bound data. In Chrome's Dev Tools I'm seeing that the requests are being made and if I update the above line to:

```
api.GoGetData().subscribe((data) => {
  this.myData = data;
  debugger;
});
```

Then I'm hitting the breakpoint and I can see the data properly.

It seems I have to manually call for a tick:

```
constructor(api: Api, appref: ApplicationRef) {
  ...
  this.api.GoGetData().subscribe((data) => {
    this.myData = data;
    appref.tick();
  });
  ...
}
```

If I do that, Change Detection is forced and my UI updates appropriately. This might work, but it can't possibly be the Angular2 way to do it.

In Angular2 RC.5, what do I need to do for Change Detection to fire when I change component variables from an Http request's Observable's subscribe callback?

**EDIT:** I've removed a lot of my existing code so I can try and get this sorted out. Here's what I have now:

index.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <app>Loading</app>
    <script src="app/lib/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/zone.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/system.js"></script>
    <script src="app/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app/boot').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

boot.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { TestComponent } from './components/test';
import { TestApi } from './components/testapi';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ TestComponent ],
  providers: [ TestApi ],
  bootstrap: [ TestComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

test.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TestApi } from './testapi';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: 'TEST<br/><br/>{{ myData }}'
})
export class TestComponent { 
  myData: any;
  constructor(private api: TestApi) {
    this.api.GoGetData().subscribe(data => {
      this.myData = data;
      console.log(this.myData);
    });
  }
}
```

testapi.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class TestApi {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  GoGetData() {
    return this.http.get('test.txt').map(res => res.text());
  }
}
```

systemjs.config.js

```
(function(global) {

  var ngVer = '@2.0.0-rc.5'; // lock in the angular package version; do not let it float to current!
  // var routerVer = '@3.0.0-rc.1'; // lock router version
  var formsVer = '@0.3.0'; // lock forms version

  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var  map = {
    'app':                        'app',

    '@angular':                   'https://npmcdn.com/@angular', // sufficient if we didn't pin the version
    'rxjs':                       'https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6'
 };

  //packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };

  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'http',
    'forms',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
  ];

  // Add map entries for each angular package
  // only because we're pinning the version with `ngVer`.
  ngPackageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    var url = pkgName;
    switch (pkgName) {
      case 'forms':
        url += formsVer;
        break;
      default:
        url += ngVer;
        break;
    }
    map['@angular/'+pkgName] = 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/' + url;
  });

  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {

    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

This is driving me crazy now! I have a `test.txt` containing "Hello from server!" and it appears just fine in the console but I only see `TEST` on the page. No errors, warnings, anything. yurzui's plnkr in the comments works for me, but not my own code.

Comment: Are you using `HTTP_PROVIDERS` or the new `HttpModule`? Second one fixed the Change Detection for me.

Comment: @Philipp In my module I'm using `HttpModule`. There is no reference to `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in my whole project.

Comment: It should work https://plnkr.co/edit/0BPsJDYRdEPussAsMbCD?p=preview

Comment: I've been going over and over with this and I see that your plnkr is working properly and I've dumbed down my code to be the same as it but for whatever reason it's not working...

Comment: It turns out that it's my `system-polyfills.js`. Without it, everything works, with it I don't see "Hello from server!" Strange...

Comment: Having the same problem with rc.5. New values get not detected, though they are set.

Comment: @ThorstenViel I was experiencing the same issue in rc.5. The cause was a font awesome script tag `<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/xxxxx.js"></script>` in my <head>. I know it's long shot but figured i'd mention.

Answer (score 0):

For my situation it turned out that something in systemjs-polyfills.js was the root cause. Simply not including it was enough to solve my issues.

Comment: This actually helps as a workaround, although excluding polyfills cannot be permanent solution.